# what does the sentence in bold mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

(Context below is from "The Soldier's Home", by E. Hemingway)

> Krebs found that to be listened to at all he had to lie, and after he had done this twice he, too, had a reaction against the war and against talking about it. A distaste for everything that had happened to him in the war set in because of the lies he had told. All of the times that had been able to make him feel cool and clear inside himself when he thought of them; the times so long back when he had done the one thing, the only thing for a man to do, easily and naturally, when he might have done something else, **now lost their cool, valuable quality and then were lost themselves**.

I think it mean that recalling those times were not soothing to him any more. I don't know if I am right or not!

Thanks before hand for your help.

Comment: I would say so. Having lied, his conscience is uneasy, and it makes him question his earlier assumptions that what he did was right.

Comment: Thank you. But does in this sentence "their" in "now lost their cool" and "themselves" in "were lost themselves" refer to "times" in "all of the times that had been able to..." ?